# Performance issue when using Views instead of Base table

Tags: oracle11g

One of our hibernate query uses view v_abc instead of table abc.
Issue is when i use view, the query is taking much time to execute instead when i use base table query is executing very fast, even though explain plan for both shows exact same reading (cost ,cardinality, joins).

Can anybody help what could be the reason for same ?

Please note: View v_abc is  'select * from abc';

Also, the hibernate query is as simple as below:

```
select v.*
from v_abc v ,pqr p
where v.col_1 =p.col_1
and p_col_2 = 123
```

;

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run the same queries without Hibernate - e.g. in SQL Plus or SQL Developer?

Comment: Yeah...the above steps are performed on sql window on pl/sql developer only. we wanted to performance tune this query, so we observed the behaviour with using view and without using view. but could not understand why query is executing fast without view even though the explain plan shows exact same figures .

Comment: That seems very odd then.  Are the view and base table on the same database (i.e. no dblink involved)?

Comment: Yes..both are on same DB.No DB links used.